# Accessing elements in Multidimensional Array of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new T1();
    ArrayList<Integer>[][] b = new ArrayList[2][3];

    b[1][2] = new ArrayList();
    b[1][2].add(1);

    //print [1]
    System.out.println(b[1][2]);
}
```

I made a 2D `array of ArrayList`. How can we check if a number has been added at a particular index of the `ArrayList` using the `if` statement?

```
if (b[1][2] == 1) // <---
    System.out.println("number 1");
```

Comment: Please rephrase _how can it is called_.

Comment: Why do you have a 2D array of `ArrayList`?  Why not have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`?? (ps `b[1][2]` will return a `ArrayList`, who would you normally get a value out of an `ArrayList`?)

Comment: Somethingy on the lines of `b.get(i)[row][column]`. Still the requirement is unclear, as to why the need of this wonderful data structure !!!!

Comment: You have two dimensional `array` of `arraylist` which mean you are working in `3 dimensional` data structure, what are you trying to achieve by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got `3 Dimensional` data structure. I don't know `what are you trying to achieve`.

---

The problem in your if condition is that you are comparing arraylist (b[1][2] contains ArrayList) with integer 1.

You can use below code

```
if (b[1][2].get(0) == 1) // checking if 1 is present at first location in the arraylist present at [1,2] location in b array.
    System.out.println("number 1");
```

or

```
if (b[1][2].contains(1)) // checking if 1 is present at any location in arraylist present at [1,2] location in b array.
    System.out.println("number 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<Integer>[][] b = new ArrayList[2][3];

 b[1][2] = new ArrayList();
 b[1][2].add(1);

 // print [1]
 System.out.println( b[1][2].get(0));
```

You need to use `get()` method of `ArrayList`.